# how to measure time to upload a file (from browser to server) in php from the server point of view?

Tags: php, timeout, metric

Does php provide api to check  multipart/form-data  upload rate , or total duration ?

I also want to know  how does PHP knows about various timeout events from IIS and php.ini settings ?

Comment: What does the second part of your question mean exactly?

Comment: an example is that if the executing php script timeout due to FastCGI activityTimeout limit , or any timeout events set in IIS or php.ini .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a value in $_SERVER you can check to find out when the request was initiated. From the PHP manual:

> 'REQUEST_TIME'
>       The timestamp of the start of the request. Available since PHP 5.1.0. It is float with microseconds since PHP 5.4.0.

So you can compare $_SERVER ['REQUEST_TIME'] against the current time() with the proviso that you're limited to a resolution of 1 second until PHP 5.4 becomes widespread.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so - the upload is finished by the time PHP can do anything to it, i.e apache gets the upload then, when finished, hands it to PHP - your script won't even run before that, so unless there is a way to get this information retrospectively I don't think you can get it from PHP alone.

The usual way to get this data is client-side using flash or javascript or both. 
For example, uploadify or swfupload are both great flash uploaders that provide client-side filesize limiting and upload progress indication to the user.

It would be so much easier if file uploading, progress indication and filesize limiting could be done by the browser itself :(

Reference:

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

http://swfupload.org/

Comment: is there any IIS , apache , or php log setting to record these metric and timeout events ?

Comment: the other (better) answers seem to have you covered :)

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, I believe you can use the [$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#refsect1-reserved.variables.server-indices) variable to do the calculation yourself, together with `time()`.